# Variations on a problem of S. Mazur

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convexity, convex-geometry

In problem 76 of the [Scottish Book](http://kielich.amu.edu.pl/Stefan_Banach/pdf/ks-szkocka/ks-szkocka3ang.pdf) Mazur asked

*Given a convex body $K$ in three-dimensional space and a point $o$ in its interior, consider the surface $S$ formed by all points $p$ such that the length of the segment $op$ equals the area of the intersection of the body $K$ and  the plane perpendicular to the segment and passing through the point $o$. Is the surface S convex?*

Convex geometers will recognize this problem as a very elegant formulation of the question: *given a convex body $K \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ with the origin in its interior, is the intersection body of $K$ also convex?*

A celebrated theorem of Busemann---who apparently didn't know he was solving one of the problems in the Scottish Book---states that a sufficient condition for $S$
to be a convex surface is that $K$ be symmetric about the point $o$.  This also holds for the $n$-dimensional version of the problem. Not to rob the theorem of its context, let me state it in a different form:

**Theorem (H. Busemann).** *An $(n-1)$-dimensional disc lying on a hyperplane of an $n$-dimensional normed space has no more area (Hausdorff $(n-1)$-dimensional measure) than any competing $(n-1)$-dimensional hypersurface with the same boundary.*

This formulation has the advantage of suggesting a natural generalization: *Do $k$-dimensional flat discs in normed spaces minimize (Hausdorff) $k$-area?* This
is one of the Busemann-Petty problems and it was recently settled affirmatively for $k=2$ by D. Burago and S. Ivanov in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.1543). However, it seems to me that Mazur's original formulation suggests another possible direction in which to generalize Busemann's theorem:

**Question.** *Given a convex body $K$ in three-dimensional space and a point $o$ in its interior, consider the surface $S$ formed by all points $p$ such that the length of the segment $op$ equals the **perimeter** of the intersection of the body $K$ and  the plane perpendicular to the segment and passing through the point $o$. Is the surface S convex?*

Just like the original question, this one should be interpreted as "give general sufficient conditions on $K$ for $S$ to be convex". In higher dimensions we can play with other elementary mixed volumes besides area and perimeter.